# How do I store Enum types into a map?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to store and retrieve an enum class so I can later find the correct type (based on configuration) and call ValueOf on it to parse a string. How do I put/get and then call the ValueOf?

In pseudo code it would look something like this:

```
enum MyType { VAL1, VAL2 };
enum MyColors { BLUE, RED };
Map<String, Class> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("key1", MyType.class);      //this is the MyType enum above
map.put("colors", MyColors.class);  //this is the MyColors enum above
...
String inputType = "colors";
String inputValue = "BLUE";
Class c = map.get(inputType);
assertEquals(MyColors.BLUE, c.ValueOf(inputValue));  //here I want MyColors.ValueOf() to get called
Class c2 = map.get("key1");
assertEquals(MyType.VAL1, c.ValueOf("VAL1"));  //here I want MyType.ValueOf() to get called
```

How can I do this?

To give some background on why I am doing this - I have multiple such enum types and I get an input which tells me what kind of enum it is (in text) and one of the values from the enum, so I want to look up the enum class from the map and then call the static ValueOf on it which will parse correctly.

Note - I do not want to store MyType objects in the map, I want to store class references

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you don't know which Enum class it is in advance, how do you expect to use it?

Comment: I have no idea what `MyMap` is.  `Class` doesn't have a `ValueOf` or `valueOf` method, so I don't understand what you're trying to do.  And if `c` is `MyMap.class`, and I don't know what `MyMap` is, I can't even guess what `c.valueOf("VAL1")` would be doing.

Comment: I have updated with some clarifications and more examples - please let me know what else would make this clearer (especially you downvoters)

Comment: @ajb, MyType is an enum; MyTypel.class is supposed to be a reference to that enum class; c is then supposed to be again that reference; c.ValueOf("VAL1") is supposed to be the equivalent of doing MyType.ValueOf("VAL1") except I don't know which of my enum-s that is so I look it up in the map

Comment: @durron597, I've put in some details but basically I am trying to process some user input and convert it into enum-s of several different types. At this point I am even just curious syntactically how you do that in Java

Comment: OK, that's clearer, and I think James has an answer (which relies on raw generic types--yuck!).  But it's not clear what you can do with the result, since the only thing you could assign `Enum.valueOf(c,"VAL1")` into is an `Object`.

Comment: It gives me back an actual Enum instance of the appropriate "class" (it doesn't feel right calling different Enum-s classes...) so I can use it throughout the rest of the app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Class enumType, String name)**

```
    enum MyType { VAL1, VAL2 };
    Map enumMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("key1", MyType.class);
    ...
    Class c = map.get("key1");
    assertEquals(MyType.VAL1, Enum.valueOf(c, "VAL1"));
```

Comment: Aha - Enum.ValueOf(Class, String) seems to do the trick! Do you know if it's not possible to do it the other way - is there a way of calling a static method through a Class reference?

Comment: Yes, by using reflection: `c.getMethod("valueOf", String.class)` gives you the method of "valueOf" and you can invoke it by `Object value = method.invoke(null, "VAL1")`. The "value" object is your enum instace

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum MyType {
    VAL1("value1"),
    VAL2("value2");

    private valueString;

    private enum MyType(String val) {
        valueString = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return valueString;
    }
}
```

It looks like you want to use the String as a key so define your MyType enum and then to set and get values:

```
Map<String, MyType> enumMap = new HashMap<String, MyType>();
enumMap.put("key", MyType.VAL1);

...

MyType keyVal = enumMap.get("key1");
String settingValue = keyVal.toString();  // will be "value1"
```

Comment: Adding MyType to the definition will make it work only with MyType. You have to make the value be something that extends enum: <K extends Enum<K>>

Comment: The OP only specified they wanted to store that type. If the question were different so would my answer.

Comment: I've made this more explicit in the question but I am indeed trying to store a reference to the enum in the map so I can call ValueOf dynamically later on. I do have multiple enums types.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Class as the second type, use your enum's type.

```
enum MyType { VAL1, VAL2 };

public static void main (String args[]){
    Map<String,MyType> map = new HashMap<String,MyType>();
}
```

Comment: The goal is to be able to look up the type dynamically - updated the question with more details.